# Display splines - problem with conditional expression

Tags: plotting, splines, display

I have implemented cubic spline on my own and it is working properly (table `SplineProbe` consists piecewise of cubic functions).
Right now I would like to display in on a grid of 100 points.

What I did is creating the following (`xList` contains the x-values of the grid):

```
ConditionalTable = 
  Table[With[{i = i}, 
    ConditionalExpression[SplineProbe[[i]][#], 
      xList[[i]] <= # <= xList[[i + 1]]] &], {i, 1, 99}];

Trial = Table[
   Plot[ConditionalTable[[i]][x], {x, First[xList], Last[xList]}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}], {i, 1, 99}];

   Apply[Show, {Trial, ListPlot[Points], PlotStyle -> Gray, 
  PlotRange -> All}]
```

The result I obtain looks like that:

[image]

When I am trying to display the ommited parts separately, it works only if the bounds are the ones the particular spline has been defined for:

```
TrialPart = Plot[ConditionalTable[[2]][x], {x, 0.002, 0.003}, 
  PlotStyle -> Dashed]
```

[image]

Here combination of those two (small dashed part between 2nd and 3rd point):

[image]

The funny thing is, if I apply the whole thing on a narrower domain, it works properly:

[image]

I am so confused, I don't even know where to look for my mistake. Each hint would come in handy for me.

**Edit:**

It is as if the `ConditionalExpression` function couldn't manage long intervals. The first five elements of the `xList` are `{0.001,0.002,0.003,0.004,0.005}`. If I try to obtain:

```
trial1 = Plot[ConditionalTable[[1]][x], {x, 0.001, 0.005}]
trial2 = Plot[ConditionalTable[[2]][x], {x, 0.001, 0.005}]
trial3 = Plot[ConditionalTable[[3]][x], {x, 0.001, 0.005}]
trial4 = Plot[ConditionalTable[[4]][x], {x, 0.001, 0.005}]

Apply[Show, {trial1, trial2, trial3, trial4, PlotRange -> All}]
```

it works:

[image]

As soon as I widen my domain, it stops working properly:

```
trial1 = Plot[ConditionalTable[[1]][x], {x, 0.001, Last[xList]}]
trial2 = Plot[ConditionalTable[[2]][x], {x, 0.001, Last[xList]}]
trial3 = Plot[ConditionalTable[[3]][x], {x, 0.001, Last[xList]}]
trial4 = Plot[ConditionalTable[[4]][x], {x, 0.001, Last[xList]}]

Apply[Show, {trial1, trial2, trial3, trial4, PlotRange -> All}]
```

[image]

Comment: What happens if you use the following options in `Plot`: `PlotPoints -> 4n` where `n` is the number of `SplineProbes` you  have and additionally `MaxRecursion->5`?

Comment: It works! Thank your very much :) 

But why doesn't it work without those options? It seems like a casual iteration.